# AppCenter Google Play deploy

Tags: azure-devops, google-developers-console, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I'm trying to deploy and Android Apk to Play store through Appcenter and Azure DevOps pipelines, during the store association I need a token for which I created a service account and generated a .json file.

The problem is that all the examples online tells me to use "owner" role, that access level is not allowed because the implementation of App Center is in testing phase and I should not be messing around with production apps, also my knowledge in GCP is pretty much null.

What I want to know is which roles / access rules I must give the service account to give AppCenter connection and permission to release to Alpha/Beta for a certain draft App

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the document "[Publish to Google Play Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/googleplay)" to try the deployment process.

At first, you should try the steps on your local machine to make sure the related steps can work. Then move the steps to Azure Pipelines to try.